# Input string was not in correct format any tips?

Tags: c#, asp.net

On the previous page i have

```
protected void SqlCheckout_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    string CustID;

    if (e.Exception == null)
    {
        CustID = e.Command.Parameters["@CustomerID"].Value.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("Payment.aspx?id=" + CustID);
    }
}
```

Then on my payment page

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    int intCustID;
    int intOrderID;

    intCustID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["CustomerID"]);

    //save shopping cart
    ShoppingCart objCart;

    //retreive shoppping cart from session
    objCart = (ShoppingCart)Session["shoppingCart"];
    //the shopping cart cannot be empty
    if (objCart != null)
    {
        //save Cart
        intOrderID = objCart.SaveCart(intCustID);
        e.Values["OrderID"] = intOrderID;
        Session["OrderID"] = intOrderID;

    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Im following a tutorial EDIT: That allows me to insert data into a database, and for some reason at this line of code Im getting an error saying Input string was not in correct format EDIT: and The ' value cannot be null' ... any tips?

Comment: -1, what is the value you are trying to parse?  When asking a question, please think about what information YOU would want to solve this problem for someone else.

Comment: sorry, my user name says it all

Comment: Not too late to add in the missing info :)

Comment: hopefully this might help?

Comment: Really all we need is your query string.  Your current code is pulling the value for `id` in your query string.  So we need: `http://mywebsite.com/mypage.aspx?id={this value!}`

Comment: I added an answer based on your update.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

The querystring parameter `id` is not an integer.

If you're unsure of the validity of a parameter, use TryParse instead.

```
int intCustId;
if(int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out intCustId)
{
  // Do stuff
}
else
{
  // Handle error
}
```

Comment: I think TryParse is faster too

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure `Request.QueryString["id"]` is not null or empty.

```
int intCustID  = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) ? 0 : int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

This will:

- Check if your `Request.QueryString["id"]` is null or empty.
- if yes, it will return zero otherwise, it will parse the string to `int`
- Assign parsed `int` value to `intCustID`

You can also use :

```
int intCustID  = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment:

> Im getting an error saying Input string was not in correct format
>   EDIT: and The ' value cannot be null' ... any tips?

It sounds like when you arrive on this page you do not have `id` in the query string.  So most likely your url looks like this:

```
http://mysite.com/mypage.aspx
```

and it needs to look like this:

```
http://mysite.com/mypage.aspx?id=1234
```

In order to fix this you will most likely need to go to the previous page (the page that you navigate TO the page with the error FROM) and figure out why `id` isn't getting passed in the query string.

**UPDATE**

Your original code suggested you were trying to pull:

```
Request.QueryString["id"]
```

While your update suggests:

```
Request.QueryString["CustomerID"]
```

Based on your comment below neither of these are correct.  You need to match the query string exactly (including case).  Try the code below:

```
Request.QueryString["ID"]
```

As other's have mentioned you should probably be using `TryParse` also.

Comment: Take a look at my update.  I suspect this is just a case sensitivity issue.

Comment: <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="~/Checkout.aspx" runat="server">Checkout</asp:HyperLink>

The user must click this in order to navigate to the check out page? could that have something to do with the data not being pased correctly

Comment: Why did you remove your comment with the URL?  Please add it back in.

Comment: http://localhost:2268/Project%20improved3/Checkout.aspx

 and 

http://localhost:2268/Project%20improved3/Payment.aspx?id=

Comment: That's different from every other URL you have posted so far.  If you can't provide consistent information it will be impossible to track down your problem.  The issue lies in what is in your query string.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the the string that `Request.QueryString["id"]` returns is not an integer.

What you get is probably either

- empty, so that you are trying to convert an empty string
- a non-numeric string, which obviously cannot be converted to an integer
- a decimal format number, like "5.0", instead of "5", which also would give this exception. In that case you can use `double.Parse` instead, and convert to int afterwards.